# What are Voronoi cells for FCC and HCP Lattices lattices in space?

Tags: polyhedra, packing-problem, vector-lattices

What are Vornoi cells for FCC and HCP Lattices ? (See plot below for FCC and HCP).

Is my uderstanding correct that we should get one of the 5 "[parallelohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelohedron)"  ?

If so, that seems to contradict [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres#Filling_the_remaining_space): "If, instead, every sphere is augmented with the points in space that are closer to it than to any other sphere, the duals of these honeycombs are produced: the rhombic dodecahedral honeycomb for fcc, and the trapezo-rhombic dodecahedral honeycomb for hcp." 
Because trapezo-rhombic dodecahedral is not the list of parallelohedra. Or I misreading something ?

---

[FCC and HCP:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres#FCC_and_HCP_Lattices)

FCC and HCP are densiest sphere packing lattices in R^3, which can be seen, as the same for the first two layers, but the third layer is positioned differently:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres
[image]

PS
Motivation - to understand 3-d analogue of : 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362135/does-the-plane-clustered-to-minimize-sum-distances2-to-clusters-centers-inert

Comment: Who said they must be parallelohedra? This is certainly not the case for HCP.

Comment: @IvanNeretin lattice is object  invariant under parallel translation, is not it ? Or  HCP is not a lattice in that mathematical sense ?

Comment: That's right, HCP is not a lattice in this sense. Not all balls in HCP are translationally equivalent.

Comment: @IvanNeretin thank you, what HCP is then ?  You might think of converting comments into the answer, may be providing some details...

Comment: Still Wiki mentions "Brave lattice" (which IS lattice in translation sense) what is the relation with HCP ?

Comment: Well, HCP is just what it is. You have seen all these pictures with spheres. Sure, it contains some repeated unit cell. If we throw out all spheres from HCP and just deal with the unit cell, we'll recognize it as primitive hexagonal.

Comment: So the translation symmetry group of HCP is isomorphic to Z^3, but it does does not act transitively on whole set of spheres ?

Comment: Exactly.$\mathstrut$

Comment: @IvanNeretin seems that Wiki page deserves the correction - it says "lattice" and gives the precise link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group) in the first sentence. Agree ? While  HCP  is NOT a lattice in that sense, as you suggest. Russian wiki seems to be more correct just say "packing" not using word "lattice".