# If you fill space with spheres and inflate them

Tags: spheres, packing-problem

Say that you were to fill space with spheres and inflate them what shape would the bounds make?

We can assume the spheres are packed optimally, just like you would stack cannon balls, what kind of shape would these form?

We already know that the shape tiles 3D space perfectly.

It's a relatively simple question, and i thought it could have been a cubotahedron, but i wanted to make sure and ask you, since i couldnt find a good answer and the cubotahedron doesnt seem to tile space.

Comment: There are two ways to optimally stack equal spheres. This will affect your shapes. Also, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714010/what-are-voronoi-cells-for-fcc-and-hcp-lattices-lattices-in-space for a very similar question.

Comment: really? i thought they were there was only one, starting with a square grid base. 
and that would be equivalent to starting with a triangle grid base?

Comment: If you start with hexagonal packing in one layer, and then hexagonal packing in the layer above, the spheres of the third layer can either be entirely aligned with the spheres in the first layer, or not. This will obviously affect what shape the second layer spheres get.

Comment: Of course! That makes sense.
here's a thing i did in the mean time: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tz12s6dtzs
now i just have to find out how to render voronoi shapes i guess.
thx a lot.

Comment: It might be worth looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_dodecahedral_honeycomb and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitruncated_cubic_honeycomb